# Don't know why my loop does not loop

Tags: c#, loops, variable-assignment, do-while

I'm new at programming and have been working on a program that converts a saunas temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius and then tells the user if he/she should turn the heat up or down depending on the original input number. I've done the majority of my code but now I can't see why it does not loop when I write a number below 73 degrees or over 77 degrees. Can anyone see the problem that my eyes seem to not find?

```
using System;

namespace BastunKP
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int FahrToCels(int fahr)
        {
            int tempCels = (fahr - 32) * 5 / 9;
            return tempCels;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Skriv in Fahrenheit: ");
            int fahr = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int tempCels = FahrToCels(fahr); 

            do
            {
                if (tempCels < 73)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är för kallt, skruva upp lite!");
                }
                else if (tempCels > 77)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är för varmt, skruva ner lite!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är nu lagom, hoppa in!");
                    return;
                }

                fahr = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                tempCels = FahrToCels(fahr);
            }           
            while (tempCels < 73 && tempCels > 77);
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a question regarding my assignment where the teacher has said that for a higher grade I should look into where the formula for converting fahrenheit to celsius and make it a double but I dont know how to do this change at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Look at condition in while

Comment: And why are there two `else` statements for the `if`?

Comment: @creyD Nvm that one, I forgot to take that one out in the post.

Comment: @Kian Ah okay, I thought it would be something like that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Now, let's get down to your question:

First off, consider your `do-while` loop.

```
do {
    if (tempCels < 73) {
        // Temperature too high
        Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är för kallt, skruva upp lite!");
    } else if (tempCels > 77) {
        // Temperature too low
        Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är för varmt, skruva ner lite!");
    } else {
        // Temperature just right, hop in!
        Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är nu lagom, hoppa in!");
        return;
    }

    fahr = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    tempCels = FahrToCels(fahr);

}
while (tempCels < 73 || tempCels > 77);
```

As you can see, I removed the unnecessary else condition. What happens right now, is that all possible conditions are checked (`temp < 73`, `temp > 77`, and `73 < temp < 77`).

One mistake you had, also pointed out in other answers, is that you had `&& (AND)` instead of `|| (OR)`. And of course, a value cannot be both under 73 and above 77 :)

Now, I'd like to also point out some styling / general things I think you should 'fix':

1) Your temp conversion method contains an unnecessary variable creation and assignment. You can make it work just as well without it, like this:

```
    public static int fahrToCels(int fahr) {
        // It returns just the same, without needing to create a new, 
        // temporary temperature variable! 
        return (fahr - 32) * 5 / 9;
    }
```

2) This might be debatable, but general naming conventions say that function names are written with camelCase.

3) While this is not a problem in your scenario specifically, it might become one when you scale up an application (or work on a bigger one).
It's best to use slightly more descriptive namings (in a bigger project, just fahr might be confusing). Again, it's not any big deal of a problem, just something for you to consider for the future :)

P.S. I did not change variable names in my examples, just to keep it more readable/relateable to the code you showed.

**EDIT:**

As per request, here is how to keep the values as `double` type.

```
    // Notice the return type and the property types are both double.
    public static double fahrToCels(double fahr) { 
        return (fahr - 32) * 5 / 9;
    }
```

This way, values don't have to be only integers, and produce weird results on division - they can be of type double too!

Now, remember you will need to pass a variable of type double to the function, otherwise you will get a type error.

Hint:

```
double fahr = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Will let the user pass a non-integer value (like, say, 17.7), and it will be stored properly.

Hint #2:

If you really want to do on the fly conversion, you can achieve this like this (example values):

```
int ourInteger = 4;
double ourNewDoubleNumber = (double)ourInteger / 23;
```

You can read more about types and type casting here: [Types and Type Casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will keep your precious feedback and keep it by heart when doing future projects. Did you also happen to know something about my last paragraph? With my teacher saying that for a higher grade I should be able to convert the "(fahr - 32) * 5 / 9;" to a double somehow?

Comment: Yeah. Since you are doing division, you might end up with a non-integer value. This means you might want to have all your variables (both tempCels and fahr) as doubles.

Comment: And How do I do that? I've tried some convert.toDouble and Double.parse but not one of them works

Comment: Why parse, when you can have them as double right from the start? That will also allow people to input doubles. I'll edit my question to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

`tempCels < 73 && tempCels > 77` is never true!

Most probably you wanted `||` so to run when temp is less than `73` or greater than `77`, but who knows.

Comment: this one was easy

Comment: okey! Do you know something about the last paragraph I wrote? About converting the formula for making fhar to celsius as a double?

Comment: This is off topic for SO.

Comment: Can you help me somewhere else than here then? Or make a new post?

Comment: I cannot because you ignored my answer for you.

Comment: No you didn't ;)

Answer (score 2):

`tempCels` (or any number, for that matter) can't be less than 73 and more than 77 at the same time. You should use the logical `||` operator, not the logical `&&` operator:

```
do {
    // code
} while (tempCels < 73 || tempCels > 77);
// Here ---------------^
```

Comment: Do you know something about the last paragraph I wrote? About converting the formula to a double?

Comment: @Kian just use `double`s and floating point literals (e.g., `5.0` instead of `5`).

Comment: My teacher gave us a hint and told us that this is how it should look like:

public static double FahrToCels(int fahr)
{
 //Type convert "Fahr" to a floating decimalnumber
 //Do the calculation with decimals in the answer
 return temp;
}

Answer (score 0):

`while` will loop when the condition is true, but `tempCels` cannot be `<73` and `>77` at the same time! Fix that condition and it will work.